# LWUIT html component shows out of memory error

Tags: html, components, lwuit

Please help me to do this.
I have to retrieve data from website url and show it in form using lwuit html component. But I have retrieved the data from html component and while showing it shows out of memory eror.

My app jar size; 1579 KB
SDK : Nokia SDK 1.0 for java
SDK heap size:4 MB
SDK jar size: 2 MB

```
htmlComp.setPage(URL);
htmlComp.getDocumentInfo().setPostRequest(true);
htmlComp.setIgnoreCSS(true);
htmlComp.getDocumentInfo().setEncoding("UTF-8");
```

I don't know why it run out of memory error

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that the HTML file/data are too large but there was also a bug in the XML parser code used in LWUIT (which I guess Nokia didn't fix) we did fix it however in [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com). I don't recall where it was exactly but there was an infinite loop that ran forever, we also improved the performance noticeably by reducing string concatenation.